# getElementByClassName multiple use and display in <title>

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the getElementByClassName function to change the displayed text. 
I'm running into 2 different problems.

Problem 1:
I want to change my `<title></title>` to the value of `var value`.
It doesnt work the like the displayed text in the body element.

Problem 2: 
Now I'm using 4 different variables because I can only declare a `getElementsbyClassName` once every `class`. I there a way to write this code more beautiful/compacter?

Any help would be appricated,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <title><!--VALUE HERE<div class="div0"></div>--></title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>    
        
    <script>
    var value= "Banana"; 
    //var vartest0 = document.getElementsByClassName("div0");    
    var vartest1 = document.getElementsByClassName("div1");
    var vartest2 = document.getElementsByClassName("div2");
    var vartest3 = document.getElementsByClassName("div3");    
    //vartest0[0].innerHTML =  value;    
    vartest1[0].innerHTML =  value;
    vartest2[0].innerHTML =  value;
    vartest3[0].innerHTML =  value;    
    </script>        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d suggest:

```
// use document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve all the elements
document.querySelectorAll(".div1,.div2,.div3")
  // use NodeList.forEach() to iterate over all the
  // returned Nodes
  .forEach(
    // using an Arrow function ("el" is a reference to the
    // current Node of the NodeList), here we update the
    // textContent of each Node to the "value" variable:
    (el) => el.textContent = value);
// and set the document.title to that same variable:
document.title = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the value for title, you need to do `document.title = "Banana";` or `document.title = value;`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <div class="div3"></div>    
        
    <script>
    var value= "Banana"; 
    document.title = value;  
    var vartest1 = document.getElementsByClassName("div1");
    var vartest2 = document.getElementsByClassName("div2");
    var vartest3 = document.getElementsByClassName("div3");    
    //vartest0[0].innerHTML =  value;    
    vartest1[0].innerHTML =  value;
    vartest2[0].innerHTML =  value;
    vartest3[0].innerHTML =  value;    
    </script>        
</body>
</html>
```